# fancyapp popup not working in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox-2

I have created a simple popup using fancyapp. It is working great in browsers but for mobile version, when i added the meta tag as
 `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />`
then the popup stopped working nicely in mobile. here is the [link](http://goo.gl/77TvSK).

The exact problem is I have to use the meta tag and my popup stops to scroll in mobile and hence popup content is cut off.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: try placing the `DOCTYPE` before the opening `<html>` tag

Comment: DOCTYPE has been already added.

Comment: I never said it wasn't there, I just said it is not in the right order so your page runs in quirks mode. Read my previous comment again.

Comment: Sorry. I have now added before HTML, but it still didn't worked.